# Trying to import my javascript code to one js file and create an html page from it

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on the Odin Project's Restaurant page project. I am trying to get my functions to import on my index.js page, and call from there ("let’s write this initial page-load function inside of it’s own module and then import and call it inside of index.js"). Right now I am trying to write out my index.js file so that I can add my javascript files like initial-page-load.js in order and call them to make a full html page. Any help would be appreciated.

initial-page-load.js:

```
const initalPageLoad = (() => {
    const content = document.querySelector('#content');

    const header = document.createElement('header');

    header.innerHTML = `
        <nav>
        <a href='#' class='menuIcon'>
            <span class='home'></span>
            <span class='about'></span>
            <span class='contact'></span>
        </a>
        <ul class='link'>
            <li data-tab-target="#home" class="page">Home</li>
            <li data-tab-target="#menu" class="page">Menu</li>
            <li data-tab-target="#contact" class="page">Contact</li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
    `

    content.appendChild(header)
})();

export { initalPageLoad }
```

index.js:

```
import { intialPageLoad } from "./intial-page-load"
import { homePageLoad } from "./home";
import { menuPageLoad } from "./menu";
import { contactPageLoad } from "./contact";
```

Comment: did you forget to call the functions once you have imported them?

Comment: so under my code in index.js should I put initialPageLoad().. etc and my file would appear?

Comment: yeah, remember all you are doing is importing functions. You have to call functions to expect them to do their thing!

Comment: You will find `initialPageLoad` to be `undefined`. The IIFE has no return statement, so the nothing is assigned to the variable that is exported. Contrary to what Coder100 said, you can remove everything (including the IIEF and export statement) from that file you have provided and import the file directly as `import './inital-page-load.js'` and the code will execute and do its thing.

Comment: yeah, that works too, but I presumed he had them in functions for a reason.
Also I didn't notice the IIFE, thanks for reminding them that!